# How to set variable with the multiple lines output of a named template in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Having a multiple line named template like this (simplified for testing purposes):

```
{{- define "sample.callee" }}
- |
  echo "test 1"; \
  echo "test 2";
{{- end }}
```

How can this be used to assign a variable (particularly in another named template), close to the below sample (any other logic removed)?

```
{{- define "sample.caller" }}
{{- $commands := include "sample.callee" . }}
{{- end }}
```

**EDIT**

The only way I've managed to get a list out of it was to make a map out of the template output and getting back the value:

`{{ $commands : = ( get ( ( printf "list:\n %s" ( include "sample.callee" . ) ) | fromYaml ) "list" ) }}`

Comment: I think exactly the syntax you show should work (`$command`'s scope being limited to the caller template).  What happens when you include this in a larger chart?

Comment: The error is "error calling include: template"

Comment: Looks like there is an extra newline at the beginning of the template output.

Comment: That's possible; putting a `-` inside the `}}` at the end of the `define "callee"` line will fix that.

Comment: Indeed, it's a matter of that and initial operator `- |` that seems to break it. I've removed the `- |` and I've moved the indentation at call time and started to work.  I am not really satisfied by the solution.